# How to correctly output specific cURL response from POST request

Tags: php, curl

I'm running a cURL post request that is appearing to hit the url and return a response. However, I'm led to believe that I'm not handling the request output properly and it's throwing an error that I don't understand. I'm extremely new to cURL and if anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'XXX',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        client_id => 'XXX',
        client_secret => 'XXX',
        member_id => 'XXX'
    ],
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC
]);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

var_dump(json_decode($resp, true));
```

This results in the errors that follows:

```
{"errors":{"":["Input string '--------------------------cec6101ba64bcb7f' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 42."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"80031695-0002-ef00-b63f-84710c7967bb"}
```

Comment: Looks like PHP. Mind tagging it ?

Comment: That does not seem to be a problem with cURL itself. The response is from the requested endpoint (probably an API?). So it seems that either the response from the requested endpoint is in fact correct or that you are not providing the right data for it. Without knowing the endpoint it is hard to help.

Comment: @Andreas you are correct. The response was telling me that my input of the post fields was incorrect. I changed the format to json_encode my post fields prior to sending the request (Example below) and it seems to have worked. Im receiving my response now with the token stored in an array. I'll post the full answer now.                                                       
       $data = array(
  "ClientId" => "$api_clientId" ,
  "ClientSecret" => "$api_clientSecret",
  "MemberId" => "$api_memberId"
 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$curl = curl_init();

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
);
//////
 Adding this and using json_encode allowed for the request to be properly sent with the required id's and secret tokens.
//////
$data = array(
    "ClientId" => "$api_clientId" ,
    "ClientSecret" => "$api_clientSecret",
    "MemberId" => "$api_memberId"
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://staging.micromerchantsystems.com/authenticationservice/api/GateKeeper/createtoken',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC
]);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

var_dump(json_decode($resp, true));
```